# Align different elements horizontally in a header

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to align 3 different elements in my menu, I've tried many things but without any success.

index.html:

```
<header>
  <nav class="main-menu">
    <img class="logo" src="img/teste.svg" alt="">
    <ul class="links-menu">
      <li><input type="text" name="" value=""></li>
      <li>Carreiras & Formações</li>
      <li>Para Empresas</li>
      <li>Como Funciona</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="register-menu">
      <li>Entrar</li>
      <button type="button" name="button">Matricule-se</button>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

default.css:

```
header {
  background: rgb(28, 119, 149);
  width: 70%;
  height: 4.5em;
  margin: .5em 15%;
  border-bottom: #8a8a8a;
  border-width: .2em;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-menu{
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Have also a reset.css referred to in the HTML, any help?

Comment: Just to clarify, what 3 elements specifically are you referring to? Also, do you mean that you want to center justify these 3 said elements, or do you mean that you want them all on the same baseline?

Comment: the <img>, and the two <ul> lists, and i want all on the same baseline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is to target your UL elements, and set the display property to `display: inline-block`. I would do the same thing to your `li` elements, so that you can adjust the padding and margins of them. See my example below (note, I'd view it in "full page" view to get the full result)

```css
header {
  background: rgb(28, 119, 149);
  width: 70%;
  height: 4.5em;
  margin: .5em 15%;
  border-bottom: #8a8a8a;
  border-width: .2em;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-menu{
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul, li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="main-menu">
    <img class="logo" src="img/teste.svg" alt="">
    <ul class="links-menu">
      <li><input type="text" name="" value=""></li>
      <li>Carreiras & Formações</li>
      <li>Para Empresas</li>
      <li>Como Funciona</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="register-menu">
      <li>Entrar</li>
      <li>
        <button type="button" name="button">Matricule-se</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use flexbox?
Something like:

```css
header {
  background: rgb(28, 119, 149);
  width: 100%;
  height: 4.5em;
  border-bottom: #8a8a8a;
  border-width: .2em;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-menu{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.links-menu, .register-menu {  
  list-style: none;
}

.links-menu li{  
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="main-menu">
    <img class="logo" src="img/teste.svg" alt="">
    <ul class="links-menu">
      <li><input type="text" name="" value=""></li>
      <li>Elements</li>
      <li>Para Empresas</li>
      <li>Como Funciona</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="register-menu">
      <li>Entrar</li>
      <button type="button" name="button">Matricule-se</button>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , hope it works too.

```
.main-menu {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
```

}

Make these changes to your main-menu class